# Changing the working directory using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, typo3

I run TYPO3 with a normal site and a subdomain in the same TYPO3 installation. On the normal site, automatically a mobile device is detected and then rerouted to the subdomain.
In my subdomain the visitor is redirected to the correct page in the TYPO3 tree, using following .htaccess file.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^m.mysite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.mysite.com/index.php?id=74 [L]
```

What happens is that the visitor ends up in an endless loop where he is sent to the TYPO3 site and then to the subdomain and back again.

To get this working, I also need to change the working directory to www.mysite.com (I also have another provider where I can make these changes using a cpanel, and that site runs perfectly). I have been looking everywhere and have tried almost anything, but I simply do not have enough knowledge to change the working directory.

So what code should I use to change the working directory?

Comment: See michael's solution below. Beside that, I would also replace `http://m.mysite.com/index.php?id=74` with just `/index.php?id=74`

Answer (score 0):

Use `RewriteCond` to *not* follow this rule for `index.php`.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^m.mysite.com [NC]

# Failing the index.php check, the usual test is to look for any
# existing file

# EDIT: Changed URI to start with / - should work per comments
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php 
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.mysite.com/index.php?id=74 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks Michael,
But this does not work :-(.
It remains in an endless loop. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: @Ton see edit above. Not sure if this will work for your situation

Comment: @ron `%{REQUEST_URI}` starts with a `/` where the first parameter of RewriteRule does not. If you had used `!^/index.php` it would have worked. Or you could have used `RewriteCond $1 !^index.php`.